# Connect 2 mysql queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:

**users**

id | user

**likes**

id | owner | date

And this query:

```
$owner_result = $connector->query("SELECT id FROM users");
while($owner = $connector->fetchArray($owner_result))
{
$rs = $connector->query("SELECT count(id) AS num FROM likes 
WHERE date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) 
AND owner='$owner[id]' 
ORDER BY num DESC LIMIT 5");
while($rw = $connector->fetchArray($rs)) 

{echo "This owner ($owner[id]) has $rw[num] likes this week";}

}
```

What i want i to do is to return me 5 **users.id** rows with the most big ammount of rows in **likes** table. 
My query returns me just **$owner[id]** but not ammount of likes for each one. And i think the performance of my query is very low as well because my query checks amount of likes for every **users.id** in **likes** table, but it may be that likes **table** doesn't contain some **users.id** .

Any advice for solve my problem or improve my query will be very welcome.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a single query would get you the specified result, for example:

```
SELECT u.id
     , COUNT(t.owner) AS cnt_likes
  FROM users u
  JOIN likes t
    ON t.owner = u.id
 WHERE t.date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
 GROUP BY u.id
 ORDER BY 2 DESC
 LIMIT 5
```

An appropriate index on the `likes` table should improve performance:

```
... ON likes (owner, date)
```

Alternatively, this will give an equivalent result, possibly with (slightly) better performance:

```
SELECT u.id
     , t.cnt_likes
  FROM users u
  JOIN ( SELECT s.owner
              , COUNT(1) AS cnt_likes
           FROM likes s
          WHERE s.date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
          GROUP BY s.owner
       ) t
    ON t.owner = u.id
 ORDER BY t.cnt_likes DESC
 LIMIT 5
```

---

You would get even better performance if you were guaranteed that all the values of the `owner` column in the `likes` table were actually `id` values in the `user` table... because you could avoid the join to the users table, and get the entire result from the `likes` table:

```
SELECT s.owner
     , COUNT(1) AS cnt_likes
  FROM likes s
 WHERE s.date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
 GROUP BY s.owner
 ORDER BY cnt_likes DESC
 LIMIT 5
```

But, that query doesn't do the check to verify the value returned from the `owner` column exists as in the `id` column of the `user` table.

Comment: @Valerius Mazare: your intuition was right; it's usually much more efficient to run a single query and get a single result set from the MySQL server, than it is to do a "loop" to run multiple queries. (This also makes for cleaner code.) But, it's not *always* more efficient; there are some edge cases where running optimized singleton queries can actually be more efficient than a monstrous query with a horrendous access plan, but this is more the exception than the rule.)

Answer (score 1):

You have to do a group by owner in the second query. You can't count rows without group them first.

```
$owner_result = $connector->query("SELECT id FROM users");
while($owner = $connector->fetchArray($owner_result))
{
$rs = $connector->query("SELECT count(id) AS num FROM likes 
WHERE date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) 
AND owner='$owner[id]'
Group BY owner 
ORDER BY num DESC LIMIT 5");
while($rw = $connector->fetchArray($rs)) 

{echo "This owner ($owner[id]) has $rw[num] likes this week";}

}
```

Comment: Thank you. But it displays me only 2 entries instead of desired 5.

Answer (score 1):

You should join the two tables so you can get your data in one single statement:

```
SELECT
    users.id,
    COUNT(likes.id) AS mylikes     -- specify a name for the computed column
FROM users
INNER JOIN likes
ON users.id = likes.owner
WHERE date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
GROUP BY users.id
ORDER BY COUNT(likes.id) DESC      -- MySQL would allow the alias name 
LIMIT 5                            -- because you want the top 5
```

If there's a tie, then you will lose a record (or more).

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't display me something